# How to track down the code requesting location in background on Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location, android-10.0

I have an android app that shouldn't request location in background. But I do see a [reminder](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/background-location-access). 
Most probably it's some library, can be facebook sdk or similar. How can I find, which one?
The best way would be to crash internal builds, then I will get stacktrace. But I haven't found strict mode settings for background location access.
Any recommendations?

Comment: You could use the IDE to set a method breakpoint on the API the code uses, which is likely one of the `requestLocationUpdates()` variants.

Comment: I as said in question, I think the request coming from unknown place from one of the libraries, not from my code.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You are setting the breakpoint on the entry point for a public API, not on your own code.